# Asterisk shows No matching endpoint found

Tags: linux, asterisk, sip, pbx

I have planned to implement Asterisk SIP server for testing eMTA calls. I don't have eMTAs so I decided to start with Linux Soft client and then, when I will have an eMTA and physical access to the equipment play with eMTAs.
I installed Asterisk on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS and followed this manual https://ozeki.hu/p_1031-how-to-create-a-sip-account-in-asterisk.html

Unfortunately it doesn't work. On the console, when I place a call from 101 I am getting this:

```
Connected to Asterisk GIT-18-9024bb989b currently running on MY-HOST-NAME (pid = 2288)
[Jun  9 18:57:54] NOTICE[2498]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:676 log_failed_request: Request 'REGISTER' from '"101" <sip:101@server.ip.is.here>' failed for 'client.ip.is.here:5060' (callid: a58ff143-2d22-4600-a3f4-c6538bf98ac1) - No matching endpoint found
[Jun  9 18:57:54] NOTICE[2498]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:676 log_failed_request: Request 'REGISTER' from '"101" <sip:101@server.ip.is.here>' failed for 'client.ip.is.here:5060' (callid: a58ff143-2d22-4600-a3f4-c6538bf98ac1) - No matching endpoint found
[Jun  9 18:57:54] NOTICE[2498]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:676 log_failed_request: Request 'REGISTER' from '"101" <sip:101@server.ip.is.here>' failed for 'client.ip.is.here:5060' (callid: a58ff143-2d22-4600-a3f4-c6538bf98ac1) - Failed to authenticate
[Jun  9 18:57:54] NOTICE[2498]: res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c:676 log_failed_request: Request 'REGISTER' from '"101" <sip:101@server.ip.is.here>' failed for 'client.ip.is.here:5060' (callid: 71eb7de3-929d-4afa-b859-56e398ce91ee) - No matching endpoint found
```

Addes in users.conf

```
[100]
type=friend
username=100
callerid=100
secret=100
context=test
host=dynamic
allow=all

[101]
type=friend
username=101
callerid=101
secret=101
context=test
host=dynamic
allow=all
```

extensions.conf

```
[test]
exten => 100,1,Dial(SIP/100)
exten => 101,1,Dial(SIP/101)

PBX*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description
100/100                   (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
101/101                   (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored
2 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 2 offline]
```

As soft client, I am using jami:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scia2.png)

What am I doing wrong?
Honestly tried to use two different manuals with different approaches neither is working.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things. There are two SIP compatible channel drivers in asterisk now:

- chan_sip: the old one, which technology identifier is SIP/
- chan_pjsip: the new pjproject one, which technology identifier is PJSIP/

Your configuration (users.conf and extensions.conf) are for chan_sip, however your logs show chan_pjsip.

It would be wise to decide which one you would like to use, and disable the other one by listing it in modules.conf prefixed with noload => chan_xxxx.so